# Way of passing request format to Twig path function

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I pass request format to path function, ex xml?

**[EDIT]**

Reading the docs solved my problem: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getRequestFormat

Comment: Reading the docs often helps to solve problem and can also saves some headaches ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want to pass the _format variable in with any others that you need to define:

```
{% path('some_path', { _format: "xml"}) %}
```